# why using sizeof in malloc?

Tags: c, malloc, sizeof

When executing this code on IDEONE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct A{
    int x;
    char c;
};

struct B{
    int y;
};

int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    struct A* pa = malloc(sizeof(struct B));
    printf("%d\n",sizeof(*pa));
    pa = malloc(sizeof(int));
    printf("%d\n",sizeof(*pa));
    pa = malloc(sizeof(char));
    printf("%d\n",sizeof(*pa));
    pa = malloc(0);
    printf("%d\n",sizeof(*pa));
    return 0;
}
```

I got:

```
8
8
8
8
```

I'm guessing that since `pa` is of type `struct A *` and `struct A` is 8 bytes long, then malloc is allocating 8 bytes, as it should, but if so, why use sizeof?

Comment: why use sizeof ***as opposed to what?***

Comment: If you didn't use `sizeof` how would you know how much memory you needed to allocate for each structure?

Comment: Note that your first allocation probably allocates 4 bytes of data that you're allowed to use, but to use that space as a `struct A`, you'd need 8 bytes.  Tools like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) would complain about accessing out of bounds memory.  If you allocate insufficient memory, all hell breaks loose — it typically leads to a buffer overflow.  Fortunately, you throw away the under-allocated chunk of memory before you abuse it (but `valgrind` would complain about the leak).  Similarly with the other allocations.

Comment: `sizeof` is a *compile-time* operator. It has no idea what a pointer might actually be pointing to when the program is run. It only knows that you declared `pa` as a pointer to `struct A`, so it will give you the size of a `struct A`, period. If you force it to point to something else, well, that's your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sizeof` doesn't return the size of the memory block that was allocated (C does NOT have a standard way to get that information); it returns the size of the operand based on the operand's type. Since your pointer is of type `struct A*`, the sizeof operand is of type `struct A`, so sizeof always returns 8.

So, even if you allocate 1 byte for a 10000 byte structure, you will still see `sizeof` return 10000.

If you don't allocate enough memory for that object (e.g. because sizeof(int) < sizeof(struct A)) but you try to use the object anyway, you'll encounter undefined behaviour - your program is no longer well defined and anything could happen (nothing, crashing, memory corruption, hackers owning your computer).

Comment: Ok, thx.  I actually did try to usend the memory when I didnt allocate enough and it was fine. I'll chuck it down to undefined behavior