# getting stuck in rewriting strcpy

Tags: c

Im trying to rewrite strcpy function but im getting stuck in this, my function does not run when the first arg is the static array of chars, only run if it is an allocated pointer. I think the problem is the realloc statement in my function. Please help me for my problem...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int myStrlen(const char *);
char *myStrcpy(char *, const char *);

int main() {
    char str1[40];
    char str2[] = "one piece";
    char *str;
    str = (char*)malloc(1 * sizeof(char));
    myStrcpy(str, str2);
    printf("%s", str);
    myStrcpy(str1, str2);
    printf("%s", str1);
    return 0;
}

int myStrlen(const char *str) {
    int i = 0, len = 0;
    while (str[i++] != '\0') {
        len++;
    }
    return len;
}

char *myStrcpy(char *str1, const char *str2) {
    int len1, len2;
    len1 = myStrlen(str1);
    len2 = myStrlen(str2);
    str1 = (char*)realloc(str1, len2 * sizeof(char));
    for (int i = 0; i < len2; i++) {
        str1[i] = str2[i];
    }
    str1[len2] = '\0';
    return str1;
}
```

Please help me to make my code using pointer work...
Btw, here is my function without using pointer, any ideas?

```
void myStrcpy(char str1[], char str2[]) {
    int i = 0;
    while (str2[i] != '\0') {
        str1[i] = str2[i];
        i++;
    }
    str1[i] = '\0';
}

void myStrncpy(char str1[], char str2[], int n) {
    int i = 0;
    while (str2[i] != '\0' || i <= n) {
        str1[i] = str2[i];
        i++;
    }
    str1[i] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: `str = (char*)malloc(1 * sizeof(char));` this is wrong for multiple reasons, but I am curious? What size are you allocating? Do you understand what `malloc()` does?

Comment: Fyi, `realloc(str1,len2 * sizeof(char));` - not going to go so well for an empty string for `str2`

Comment: Duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/q/32641228/125562

Comment: @iharob: In `str = (char*)malloc(1 * sizeof(char));` statement i just want to allocate, not a specific size.

Comment: @Applepine why do you want to use malloc/realloc in strcpy? This is not what libc's strcpy does, and you cannot rely on strlen for that purpose. What is wrong with your functions in second code fragment, why do you wanted to change them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first implementation uses `realloc()` for no valid purpose. For standard function `strcpy()`, `str1` is assumed to point to an array with enough space to store a copy of `str2`.

If your intent is to implement different semantics from that of `strcpy`, make the name more explicit and pass it the address of the destination pointer because `realloc()` is likely to return a different pointer.  In your example, the original value of `str` is used after the call to `myStrcpy()`, which is incorrect.

Your second implementation is almost correct:

- You should use `size_t` for the type of `i`. Strings can be longer than `INT_MAX` on current systems.
- You should make the source strings `const`.
- `myStrncpy` should stop when `i` reaches `n`, use `&& i < n`
- Testing `i < n` **before** dereferencing the `str2` pointer allows an invalid pointer to be passed along with a zero value for `n`, which can be useful.
- `myStrcpy` and `myStrncpy` should return the destination pointer.
- Note that `myStrncpy` has much better semantics than `strncpy`.  The standard function `strncpy` does not do what most programmers expect. Its semantics are error prone, it should not be used to avoid potential confusion.

Here is a simplified version:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

size_t myStrlen(const char *str) {
    size_t len = 0;
    while (str[len] != '\0') {
        len++;
    }
    return len;
}

char *myStrcpy(char *str1, const char *str2) {
    size_t i = 0;
    while (str2[i] != '\0') {
        str1[i] = str2[i];
        i++;
    }
    str1[i] = '\0';
    return str1;
}

char *myStrncpy(char *str1, const char *str2, size_t n) {
    size_t i = 0;
    while (i < n && str2[i] != '\0') {
        str1[i] = str2[i];
        i++;
    }
    str1[i] = '\0';
    return str1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A properly written `strcpy` and `strncpy` should not need any heap allocation.

```
char *mystrcpy(char *dest, char *src)
{
    char *start = &dest[0];
    while(*src) *dest++ = *src++;
    return start;
}

char *mystrncpy(char *dest, const char *src, size_t n)
{
        size_t i = 0;
        char *start = &dest[0];
        while(*src && i < n)
        {
            *dest++ = *src++;
            i++;
        }
        for(; i < n; i++) *dest++ = 0;
        return start;
}
```

Comment: Make `i` a `size_t` as well.  Also insist that `mystrncpy` has nothing to do with `strncpy`. Alas `strncpy` does not do what most programmers expect and its semantics are so poorly understood that it should not be used at all.

Comment: still incorrect: `i <= n` should be `i < n`, the return values are incorrect, the constness is incorrect.  My remark about `strncpy` was not a call to reimplement its peculiar and mostly useless semantics.

Comment: @chqrlie: Fixed; the main semantic I was concerned about was copying at most `n` bytes.  According to this page: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/

`strncpy` should pad `dest` with null bytes until `n` is reached

Comment: the return value should be the **original** value of the destination pointer. Same for `strcpy`.  Note that for `strncpy()`, the destination is not null terminated if the source is longer than `n` characters, which is error prone.  Since you are using an index `i`, it as actually more complicated to increment `src` and `dest` than to just use the array notation.

Comment: Hah you're right, I forgot I was incrementing `dest` throughout the function

Comment: @GovindParmar: I'm afraid you forgot to set the null terminator in the destination array in `myStrcpy()`.